# How to store all values returned by a function?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make a function that transforms all strings inside a code into

string.char() with the bytecode of the string inside (for obfuscation purposes)

But I can't figure out how to store all values returned by string.byte

```
s = "hello there lua user"

s:byte(1,s:len())
```

Comment: Alternative way of obfuscation: `s = "hello there lua user"; obf = 's = "'..s:gsub('.',function(c)return'\\'..c:byte()end)..'"'`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff yes i'm putting it to string.char first and then i will bytecode the whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the values in a table. Try `t = {s:byte(1,s:len())}`.

Comment: `-1` is an easier choice than `s:len()` (which could be `#s` anyway)